# Leaderboard displaying entire list instead of pagination

Tags: java, sorting, discord, hashmap

I have a list of users (stored in a properties file) that have a level. I sort the users by their level and then send the sorted list back to the guild. I paginate the list, but its still showing all of the users instead of just 10 per page.

```java
Map<String, Integer> unsortedMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String key : prop.stringPropertyNames()) {
            String value = prop.getProperty(key);
            unsortedMap.put(key, Integer.valueOf(value));
        }

        Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = sortByValue(unsortedMap);

        EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder();

        eb.setTitle("aaaaaaaaaaaa");

        ArrayList<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            int value = entry.getValue();
            if (key.contains(".level")) {
                User users = ctx.getJDA().retrieveUserById(key.replace(".level", ""), true).complete();
                eb.addField(users.getName(), String.valueOf(value), false);
            }


        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sortedMap.size(); i++){
            pages.add(new InteractPage(eb.build()));
    }

        channel.sendMessageEmbeds((MessageEmbed) pages.get(0).getContent()).queue(success -> {
            Pages.paginate(success, pages, true);
                });


    }

    private static Map<String, Integer> sortByValue(Map<String, Integer> unsortedMap) {
        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(unsortedMap.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
                return (o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue()));
            }
        });

        Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : list) {
            sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return sortedMap;
```

Comment: Rewrote the leaderboard system and implemented the pagination and it still displays all users on a single page. The library I'm using for pagination is https://github.com/ygimenez/Pagination-Utils
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Partition the for loop into smaller parts using the for loop. Initialize the int outside of the loop and then increment the int for every entry and then divide the int by how many items you want displayed on the list. Ex:

```
int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
        i++;
        if (i % 6 == 0) {
//add page here
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).